# Como inserir lógica de validação para o checkbox e exibir mensagem caso não esteja selecionado

Tags: javascript, validação, checkbox

Atualmente, no meu quiz, o usuário pode avançar para a próxima pergunta sem ao menos selecionar uma opção de resposta.

Estou tentando colocar uma condição onde Se uma opção não for selecionada, exiba uma mensagem alertando e ao mesmo tempo, desabilite o botão para prosseguir.

Primeiro eu terminei o quiz sem tentar validar os inputs. 
Código HTML:

```html
<section class="nivelamento" id="nivelamento">
    <div class="container">
        <h2 id='teste_status' class="nivelamento-titulo">English Questions!</h2>
        
        <h6 id="progresso">Question</h6>
        <div id="teste">

            
        </div>    
    </div>
</section>
```

Meu js file:

```js
function seleciona(x){
    return document.getElementById(x);
};

function criaQuestao() {
    var myDiv = seleciona('teste');
    var h6 = seleciona('progresso');

    if(pos >= quizArray.length){
        myDiv.innerHTML = "<h2>Você acertou " + correto + ' de ' + quizArray.length + " questões</h2>"
        myDiv.innerHTML +=  "<button onClick='document.location.reload(true)' class='btn btn-danger btn-sm'>Refazer</button>";
        pos = 0;
        correto = 0;
        return false;
    }

    h6.innerHTML = 'Questão ' + (pos + 1) + ' de ' + quizArray.length;
   
    pergunta = quizArray[pos].question;
    op1      = quizArray[pos].opcao1;
    op2      = quizArray[pos].opcao2;   
    op3      = quizArray[pos].opcao3; 
        
    myDiv.innerHTML = "<h2>" + pergunta + "</h2><br>";
    myDiv.innerHTML += "<input type='radio' name='opcoes' value='A'> " + op1 + "<br>";
    myDiv.innerHTML += "<input type='radio' name='opcoes' value='B'> " + op2 + '<br>';
    myDiv.innerHTML += "<input type='radio' name='opcoes' value='C'> " + op3 + '<br><br>';
    myDiv.innerHTML +=  "<button onclick='verificaResposta()' class='btn btn-danger btn-sm'>Submit Answer</button>";


};

function verificaResposta(){
    var opcoes = document.getElementsByName('opcoes');
    for(var i = 0; i < opcoes.length; i++){
        if(opcoes[i].checked){
            opcoes = opcoes[i].value;
        } 
    }

    if(opcoes === quizArray[pos].resposta){
        correto++;
    }

    pos++;
    criaQuestao();
};

window.addEventListener('load', criaQuestao, false);
```

Depois tentei implementar a lógica de validação ainda na mesma função:

```js
function verificaResposta(){
    var opcoes = document.getElementsByName('opcoes');
    var button = document.querySelector(".clicado");
    var botao_clicado = false;
    button.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
        for(var i = 0; i < opcoes.length; i++){
            if(opcoes[i].checked){
                opcoes = opcoes[i].value;
                botao_clicado= true;
            }if(!botao_clicado){
                var myDiv = seleciona('teste');
                myDiv.innerHTML = '<h4>Selecione uma resposta<h4>'
            }
        }
    })   

    if(opcoes === quizArray[pos].resposta){
        correto++;
    }

    pos++;
    criaQuestao();
};
```

Mas depois que eu executo nada acontece. 
Alguém sabe me dizer por quê minha lógica de validação nao está funcionando?

Comment: O que seria isso: `seleciona('teste')`?

Comment: function seleciona(x){
    return document.getElementById(x);
};

Comment: Amauri, coloca o código html também.

Comment: Editei para tentar deixar mais clara a minha dúvida

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Você não está usando *checkboxes*, e sim *radio buttons*.

Tem vários problemas estruturais e de lógica no código. O mais grave é que você está usando a `div#teste` para substituir a mensagem "*Selecione uma resposta*" e a questão em si.

Outros problemas é que você usa a mesma variável `opcoes` da array para verificar a opção checada, causando alteração de valor em `opcoes.length` no laço `for`:

```
opcoes = opcoes[i].value;
```

Outra é que você está colocando um `button.addEventListener('click', ()=>{` dentro da função que já é chamada por um evento click em `onclick='verificaResposta()'`.

Esse *event handler* `.addEventListener('click'...` deveria ouvir os *radio buttons* para que quando um for checado, reabilitar o botão, e no final da função `criaQuestao()`, porque esses `addEventListener` deverão ser recriados ao inserir uma nova pergunta.

Veja como deveria ficar seu código funcionando:

```js
// array só para exemplo
quizArray = [
   {
      question: 'Pergunta 1',
      opcao1: 'A',
      opcao2: 'B',
      opcao3: 'C',
      resposta: 'B'
   },
   {
      question: 'Pergunta 2',
      opcao1: 'A',
      opcao2: 'B',
      opcao3: 'C',
      resposta: 'C'
   }
];


var pos = 0;
var correto = 0;

function criaQuestao() {
    var myDiv = seleciona('teste');
    var h6 = seleciona('progresso');

    if(pos >= quizArray.length){
        myDiv.innerHTML = "<h2>Você acertou " + correto + ' de ' + quizArray.length + " questões</h2>"
        myDiv.innerHTML +=  "<button onClick='document.location.reload(true)' class='btn btn-danger btn-sm'>Refazer</button>";
        pos = 0;
        correto = 0;
        return false;
    }

    h6.innerHTML = 'Questão ' + (pos + 1) + ' de ' + quizArray.length;
   
    pergunta = quizArray[pos].question;
    op1      = quizArray[pos].opcao1;
    op2      = quizArray[pos].opcao2;   
    op3      = quizArray[pos].opcao3; 
        
    myDiv.innerHTML = "<h2>" + pergunta + "</h2><br>";
    myDiv.innerHTML += "<input type='radio' name='opcoes' value='A'> " + op1 + "<br>";
    myDiv.innerHTML += "<input type='radio' name='opcoes' value='B'> " + op2 + '<br>';
    myDiv.innerHTML += "<input type='radio' name='opcoes' value='C'> " + op3 + '<br><br>';
    myDiv.innerHTML +=  "<button onclick='verificaResposta()' class='btn btn-danger btn-sm'>Submit Answer</button>";

   var opcoes = document.getElementsByName('opcoes');
   for(var i = 0; i < opcoes.length; i++){
      opcoes[i].addEventListener('click', ()=>{
         document.querySelector("#teste button").disabled = false;
      });
   }

};

function seleciona(x){ return document.getElementById(x); }


function verificaResposta(){
    var opcoes = document.getElementsByName('opcoes');
    var botao_clicado = false;
    var opcao;
     for(var i = 0; i < opcoes.length; i++){
         if(opcoes[i].checked){
             opcao = opcoes[i].value;
             botao_clicado= true;
         }
     }

      var myDiv = seleciona('teste');
      if(!botao_clicado && !myDiv.querySelector("h4")){
         var no = document.createElement("h4");
         var txt = document.createTextNode("Selecione uma resposta");
         no.appendChild(txt);
         myDiv.appendChild(no);
         document.querySelector("#teste button").disabled = true;
         return;
      }

    if(opcao === quizArray[pos].resposta){
        correto++;
    }

   if(botao_clicado){
       pos++;
       criaQuestao();
   }
};

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", criaQuestao, false);
```

```html
<section class="nivelamento" id="nivelamento">
    <div class="container">
        <h2 id='teste_status' class="nivelamento-titulo">English Questions!</h2>
        
        <h6 id="progresso">Question</h6>
        <div id="teste">

            
        </div>    
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Funcionou! Show.  Só precisei colocar  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", criaQuestao, false);   no começo da página. No final nao dá certo